# обновление с периодичностью оверлэй слоя (инфоокна) для маркера Google Maps JS на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api

Есть сайт. Бэкэнд - asp net mvc. БД - ms sql
На нем есть карта google maps js. При загрузке страницы инициализируется карта.Есть маркеры которые берутся из базы данных. У каждого маркера, при нажатии на котором появляется инфоокно. Инфоокно реализовано не стандартным InfoWindow, а через overlay, из-за дизайна.
В этом Overlay слое создается html div, в который, в цикле по каждому маркеру прикрепляется свой контент.
Каким образом можно сделать так чтобы:
1. С какой-то периодичностью (n) запрашивались новые данные из базы данных и обновлялись для каждого маркера свои контенты без перезагрузки страницы ?
2. И примерно такой же вопрос, как правильно обновлять маркеры, без перезагрузки страницы? к примеру, человек открыл страницу с картой, там на какой то момент есть маркеры, с другого места добавили маркеры, каким образом первому получить изменения без перезагрузки? это нужно делать 1 раз в секунду, думал удалять и по новому рисовать, но тоже не красиво, на карте постоянно будут дергаться маркеры.

Часть js метода рисования маркера и добавления клика
RetArr - массив из бд полученный при загрузке страницы. В нем лежат данные по маркерам, координаты и другая инфа.

```
RetArr.forEach(n => {                
                    n.markerac = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(n.Gpslat, n.GpsLng),
                        map: map,
                        icon: '/',
                        zIndex:10,
                        content: n.CString,                        
                    });             


                    n.markerac.addListener('click', function (e) {        

                        infoBox1 = new InfoBox({
                            latlng: this.getPosition(),
                            map: map,
                            content: n.CString
                        });

                    })
```

InfoBox

```
function InfoBox(param) {
    google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
    this.latlng_ = param.latlng;
    this.map_ = param.map;
    this.content = param.content;
    this.offsetVertical_ = -195;
    this.offsetHorizontal_ = 5;        
    var me = this;
    this.boundsChangedListener_ =
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, "bounds_changed", function () {
            return me.panMap.apply(me);
        });
    this.setMap(this.map_);
}
```

и часть метода, где создается div

```
InfoBox.prototype.createElement = function () {
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    var div = this.div_;
    if (!div) {  
        div = this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "infobox"
        var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.className = "content"
        contentDiv.innerHTML = this.content;
        function removeInfoBox(ib) {                
            return function () {
                ib.setMap(null);
            };
        }          
        div.appendChild(contentDiv);
        div.style.display = 'none';
        panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
        this.panMap();
    } else if (div.parentNode != panes.floatPane) {            
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Видимо, вебсокеты, нужны. Либо Аяксом каждую секунду на сервер стучаться

Comment: Постучаться забрать данные с периодичностью как раз не проблема. Вот как обновить данные в контенте для маркеров, не совсем понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример реализации:

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');
const dataList = [
  {
    id: '1',
    fullname: 'FirstName LastName',
    ext: null,
    address:
      'Canada, 1150-206, Lisbon metropolitan area, Lisbon, R. Júlio de Andrade 3',
    latitude: 38.719463,
    longitude: -9.1410403,
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    fullname: 'Manish Kumar',
    ext: 'jpg',
    address: 'Spain, 8018, Barcelona, Avenida Diagonal 161-163',
    latitude: 41.4053285,
    longitude: 2.1961763,
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    fullname: 'Alyona Vasyilyivna Balan',
    ext: 'jpg',
    address: 'Canada, 71121-3455, Apulia, Foggia, 40 Corso Garibaldi Giuseppe',
    latitude: 41.4625567,
    longitude: 15.5449964,
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    fullname: 'Miri Rodriguez',
    ext: 'jpg',
    address:
      'United States, 5014-256, Western Norway, Bergen, Olav Kyrres gate 41',
    latitude: 60.3903147,
    longitude: 5.3226769,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    fullname: 'Zoe Marianna Hill',
    ext: 'jpg',
    address: 'Panama, 65806-2543, Missouri, Springfield',
    latitude: 37.2034299,
    longitude: -93.2935778,
  },
];

const mapData = [dataList[0]];

function cretateGoogleMapInstance({
  apikey = null,
  handlerLoading = () => {},
}) {
  const url = apikey
    ? `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${apikey}`
    : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js`;
  const mapScript = document.createElement('script');
  mapScript.setAttribute('async', '');
  mapScript.setAttribute('defer', '');
  mapScript.setAttribute('src', url);
  mapScript.setAttribute('id', 'googleMap');
  document.head.appendChild(mapScript);
  mapScript.addEventListener('load', handlerLoading);
}

function loadingMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(app);
  mapData.forEach(item => {
    getCoords(item);
    createMarker(item, map);
  });
  drawMap(map);
  setInterval(() => {
    addNewMarkerToMap(map);
  }, 3000);
}
function drawMap(map) {
  const bounds = extendBounds(mapData);
  map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setCorrectZoom(map);
  }, 200);
}

function getCoords(item) {
  item.coords = new google.maps.LatLng(+item.latitude, +item.longitude);
  return item;
}
function createMarker(person, map) {
  const templateMarker = {
    position: person.coords,
    map: map,
    title: person.fullname,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    person: person,
  };
  if (person.icon) {
    templateMarker.icon = person.icon;
  }
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker(templateMarker);
  return marker;
}

function setCorrectZoom(map) {
  const currentZoom = map.getZoom();
  if (currentZoom > 15) {
    map.setZoom(15);
  }
}

function extendBounds(listCoords) {
  const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  listCoords.forEach(item => {
    bounds.extend(item.coords);
  });
  return bounds;
}

function addNewMarkerToMap(map) {
  const newItem = dataList[mapData.length];
  if (!newItem) return;
  mapData.push(newItem);
  getCoords(newItem);
  createMarker(newItem, map);
  drawMap(map);
}

cretateGoogleMapInstance({ handlerLoading: loadingMap });
```

```css
#app{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вы больше ответили на 2 пункт? 
или я что то не допонял? получается если есть уже маркер, то он не обновится и инфоокно для него тоже?

Comment: Если Вам необходимо обновить `title` маркера, то, наверное, надо обновить и сам маркер. Если же Вы хотите обновить доп. инфо, которая отображается при клике, то думаю, что маркер можно не обновлять. Во всем остально, я показал пример реализации переиодического добавления маркеров на карту. `setTimeout` - это иммитация Ajax-запроса. Вы сказали, что с этим проблем нет

Comment: ...хотя... если собрать маркеры в массив, то возможно, для обновления title и не нужно будет пересоздавать маркер. Надо API более детально изучить